# Could someone explain how is the this code executing?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

How is the createUser or updateUser using the unmarshalValueJs function and passing arguments.

```
    package controllers.user

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import services.user.UserServiceComponent
import domain.user.User

trait UserController extends Controller {
    self: UserServiceComponent =>0

def emailAlreadyExists(implicit reads: Reads[String]) =
    Reads[String](js => reads.reads(js).flatMap { e =>
      userService.tryFindByEmail(e).map(_ => JsError("error.custom.emailAlreadyExists")).getOrElse(JsSuccess(e))
    })

implicit val userReads = (__ \ "email").read[String](email andKeep emailAlreadyExists)
                                       .map(resource => UserResource(resource))

implicit val userWrites = new Writes[User] {
    override def writes(user: User): JsValue = {
        Json.obj(
            "id" -> user.id,
            "email" -> user.email
        )
    }
}
```

What create User passes to the unmarshalJsValue?
Where does resource come from?

```
def createUser = Action(parse.json) {request =>
    unmarshalJsValue(request) { resource: UserResource =>
        val user = User(Option.empty, resource.email)
        userService.createUser(user)
        Created
    }
}

def updateUser(id: Long) = Action(parse.json) {request =>
    unmarshalJsValue(request) { resource: UserResource =>
        val user = User(Option(id), resource.email)
        userService.updateUser(user)
        NoContent
    }
}

def findUserById(id: Long) = Action {
    val user = userService.tryFindById(id)
    if (user.isDefined) {
        Ok(Json.toJson(user))
    } else {
        NotFound
    }
}

def deleteUser(id: Long) = Action {
    userService.delete(id)
    NoContent
}
```

What is R over here? 
What get passed back to the createUser?

```
    def unmarshalJsValue[R](request: Request[JsValue])(block: R => Result)(implicit rds : Reads[R]): Result =
        request.body.validate[R](rds).fold(
            valid = block,
            invalid = e => {
                val error = e.mkString
                Logger.error(error)
                BadRequest(error)
            }
        )

}

case class UserResource(email: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` is a type variable. The definition `def unmarshalJsValue[R](request: Request[JsValue])(block: R => Result)(implicit rds : Reads[R])` reads:

- I'm a method called `unmarshallJsValue`.
- I require a type parameter that could potentially be anything.
- I require a value of `Request[JsValue]` (presumably a request contianin a JSON entity).
- I require a function that, given some value of type `R`, produces a `Result`.
- I require a value to be in `implicit` scope that is a `Reads` for type `R`. In other words, I need a way to convert a `JsValue` to an `R`, whatever `R` might happen to be. (If you look at [the docs for `Reads`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.html), you'll notice that its only method, `reads`, has this effect.)

To put it all together, entire function just says, give me some block of code that produces a `Result` from some piece of data I know how to convert to from JSON. The body of the function simply attempts to convert the JSON to the desired type (known as *unmarshalling*). If this succeeds, it runs the block. Otherwise, you get a `BadRequest` client error.

The compiler can't know whether the JSON that gets provided in real life by the client will be convertible to some type `R`, but it can require a JSON -> `R` converter, and some error handling code if it fails on real data.